# How to retrieve list on a webpage and return it to a list in android?

Tags: android, jsoup

I am trying to retrieve this

http://www.vgreleases.com/ReleaseDates/Upcoming.aspx

It is a list of upcoming titles. I just want to retrieve the list. How would i go about doing this?

I am familiar with JSOUP. Just need a little help with this one.

I also want to provide a NEXT MONTH button to go and load the titles on the next page.

How would i go about beginning and doing this?

Or is it even possible?

EDIT:

The list has a pattern like this....

```
<div class="FP_Up_Item">


    <div class="FP_Up_Date">
<b><span style="color: rgb(25, 150, 0); font-weight: bold;">01 Sep 2011</span></b> <br>  <span style="color: rgb(163, 163, 163);">17 days left</span>
</div>

<div class="FP_Up_ImageWrap"><img src="http://m3.n4g.com/8/GameProfiles/814000/814166_1_cov_med.jpg"></div>
<div class="FP_Up_TextWrap" style="width: 300px;">
<a href="/PS3/ReleaseDate-814166.aspx" style="color: rgb(105, 34, 30);"><b>Child of Eden</b></a> <br><span style="font-weight: normal; color: rgb(163, 163, 163); font-size: 10pt;">(PS3)</span><br>

</div>

 <div class="FP_Up_Score"><a href="/PS3/ReleaseDate-814166.aspx?ShowReviews=1">8.2</a></div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the div for each game using the class.  As for the next button, you can see if the reference contains "/ReleaseDates/".

```
// Get all the game elements
Elements games = doc.select("div.FP_Up_TextWrap");

// Iterator over those elements
ListIterator<Element> postIt = games.listIterator();

while (postIt.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(postIt.next().text());

}

// Get the "Next Month" element
Element next = doc.select("a[href*=/ReleaseDates/]").last();

System.out.println(next.attr("href"));
```

**To add to a list**

```
// Get all the game elements
Elements games = doc.select("div.FP_Up_TextWrap");

// Create new ArrayList
ArrayList<String> gameList = new ArrayList<String>();

// Iterator over those elements
ListIterator<Element> postIt = games.listIterator();

while (postIt.hasNext()) {
    // Add the game text to the ArrayList
    gameList.add(postIt.next().text());
}
```

Comment: So how would i load this into a list?

Comment: Instead of printing out each item, you could add it to a simple ArrayList<String>.  If you plan to have more information than the title, create a simple Game class with a title field.  Instead of printing out the text, call the setter for that field.  Add each Game object to an ArrayList in order to get them all in list form.

Comment: And how i could implement the next month button

Comment: Put it in an edit in your answer. It will be formated better and your work will be better acknowlegde

Comment: And shouldnt it be ArrayAdapter for android?

Answer (score 0):

You  could use `SAXParser` to parse that response.
 Extend the `DefaultHandler` class to do this.